# Python count/dictionary count

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
dct = {}
with open("grades_single.txt","r") as g:
    content = g.readlines()[1].strip('\n')
    for item in content:
        dct[item] = content.count(item)
        LetterA = max(dct.values())
print(dct)
```

I'm very new to python so please excuse me. This is my code so far and it works but not as it's intended to. I'm trying to count the frequency off certain letters on new lines so I can do a mathematical function with each letter. The program counts all the letters and prints them but I'd like to be able to count each letter one by one I.E 7As, new fuction 4Bs etc.

At the moment the program is printing them off in one function but yeah I'd like to split them up so I can work with each letter one by one. {'A': 9, 'C': 12, 'B': 19, 'E': 4, 'D': 5, 'F': 1}

Does anyone know how to count the frequency of each letter by letter?

> ADCBCBBBADEBCCBADBBBCDCCBEDCBACCFEABBCBBBCCEAABCBB

Example of what I'd like to count.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = "ADCBCBBBADEBCCBADBBBCDCCBEDCBACCFEABBCBBBCCEAABCBB"
>>> Counter(s)
Counter({'B': 19, 'C': 14, 'A': 7, 'D': 5, 'E': 4, 'F': 1})
```

Comment: Or even `dict(Counter(s))` if you really needed a dictionary.

Comment: @Reticality `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

`collections.Counter` is clean, but if you were in a hurry, you could iterate over all of the elements and place them into a dictionary yousrelf.

```
s = 'ADCBCBBBADEBCCBADBBBCDCCBEDCBACCFEABBCBBBCCEAABCBB'
grades = {}
for letter in s:
    grades[letter] = grades.get(letter, 0) + 1
```

Comment: I'd say that since this is 5 more lines than the `Counter` method, if you were in a hurry you'd use `Counter` :)

Comment: Since I didn't know that `Counter` existed, typing this sort of command out was a lot faster for me than looking up the reference in the API.  But I suppose you have a point.

Comment: Good call @augurar, duly noted.